# Writing into Table using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to write into table, specifically the top row and the left columns like in chess where there are A1, A2, etc. How do I write into table `rows[i].cells[j].---` . I'm just struggling with trying to write into table.

```
document.getElementById("Table").rows[i].cells[j]. ??? ;
```

Hey guys, so it's solved now. I use .textContent.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far

Answer (score 4):

You can only do it in this fashion:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = table.insertRow(0);

// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
```

or give ids to each cell and then insert values

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) method on the table with the [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector method:

```js
//Generate table
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.className = "table";
for (var y = 1; y <= 8; y++) {
  //Create row
  var row = table.insertRow();
  for (var x = 1; x <= 8; x++) {
    //Create cell
    var td = row.insertCell();
    if (x % 2 != y % 2) {
      //Set background to distinguish cells
      td.style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
    }
    //Show coordinates on mouse hover
    td.title = x + ":" + y;
  }
}
//Insert into document
document.body.appendChild(table);
//Write to specific row
table.querySelector("tr:nth-of-type(" + 2 + ") td:nth-of-type(" + 5 + ")").textContent = "1";
table.querySelector("tr:nth-of-type(" + 5 + ") td:nth-of-type(" + 2 + ")").textContent = "2";
```

```css
td {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```